# do I bundle my dependencies with wepback for production

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am using webpack to create my production bundle for running an express application.  I thought the webpack externals field would bundle up the dependencies I required to deploy without having to do a yarn install or an npm install.

My server webpack config looks like this:

```
      const config = merge(common, {
        name: 'server',
        target: 'node',
        externals: readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../node_modules'))
  .filter(x => !/\.bin|react-universal-component|require-universal-module|webpack-flush-chunks/.test(x))
  .reduce((externals, mod) => {
    externals[mod] = `commonjs ${mod}`;
    return externals;
  }, {});
```

I can see the following entry for express in the list of externals:

```
express: 'commonjs express',
```

But when I try and execute the file with the script that requires the express dependency I get:

> Cannot find module 'express'

I thought the whole point of externals was to specify what should be bundled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought the whole point of externals was to specify what should be
>   bundled.

Is the opposite, from the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/):

> The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding
>   dependencies from the output bundles. Instead, the created bundle
>   relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's environment.

So you don't want `express` in your externals, because it will actually be excluded from the bundle.

Comment: what is the best way?  npm on the live server?

Comment: or why am i specifying commonjs for something i exclude

Comment: I normally do this on the CI Server, install dependencies etc. If you don't have one you could do it on the server

Comment: I'm not sure why you need `commonjs` as that's natively supported by node?

Comment: i mean why specify anything for something i am excluding

Comment: You would only specify something in your externals if you are using it in your code but you don't want webpack to bundle it. An example, your application relies on angularjs but angular is already present in the environment you're running your app (via a script tag for example), therefore you don't need wepback to include angular in your app bundle.